# Compare two digits elegant solution

Tags: php

I have the following two variables:

```
$addressphone='5612719999';
$googlephone='561-271-9999';
```

Is there an elegant solution in `PHP` that can validate that these two variables actually are equal. I'd prefer not to use `str_replace` as the conditions can change and I'd have to account for everything.

**I've tried `casting` and `intval` but neither seemed to work**

**UPDATE**

```
$addressphone='5612719999';
$googlephone='561-271-9999';
preg_replace("/\D/","",$googlephone);
var_dump($googlephone);
```

returns  `string(12) "561-271-9999"`

Comment: take only digits from  strings

Comment: @splash58 Yes but with what? preg replace?

Comment: `preg_replace("/\D/","",$input)` should help.

Comment: You need to assign the value `$googlephone = preg_replace("/\D/","",$googlephone);`.

Comment: See my updated answer and @NietTheDarkAbsol's comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm kind of reiterating what the comments say, but you should remove the non-digits from each string and them compare their integer values.

```
// original, non-integer-infested strings
$addressphone= "5612719999";
$googlephone= "561-271-9999";

// remove non-digits
$addressphone = preg_replace("/\D/","",$addressphone);
$googlephone = preg_replace("/\D/","",$googlephone);
```

and then you can check the following condition for equality:

```
// compare integer values of digit-only strings
intval($addressphone) == intval($googlephone)
// should return true
```

Comment: `preg_replace` is not by-reference. You need to re-assign the return values.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Ooops sorry haven't used PHP in a while. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `preg_replace()` to remove all non-numeric characters.  That way, you're just working with numeric strings, which you can compare any way you'd like.

```
<?php
    $testString = "123-456-7890";
    echo preg_replace("/\D/", "", $testString); //echos 1234567890
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

`print_r($addressphone === implode("", explode("-",$googlephone)))`

Comment: "conditions can change" &mdash; it may not be limited to dashes as separators.

Comment: Why not just `str_replace('-', '', $string);`?

Comment: Because some people choose to use '.' in place of '-'.  There are many formatting options available for telephone numbers.  Also, it's nice to have a solution for unforeseen possibilities.

Comment: I mean using `explode` and `implode` for string replacement doesn't make sense when there is a string replacement function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pieces = explode("-", $googlephone);
$newstring=""; 
foeach ($piece in $pieces)
{
$newstring +=piece;
}
```

Now compare your string with $newstring.

Answer (score 0):

Remove everything that isn't a digit:

```
<?php

$addressphone ='5612719999';
$googlephone  ='561-271-9999';

$number_wang = function($numberish) {
    return preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $numberish);
};

assert($number_wang($googlephone) == $addressphone);
```

Comment: Oops, didn't notice the other answers that used this method:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/34440981/3392762 .